# How to groupby a column and count total numbers of other columns while excluding NaN?

Tags: python, pandas, count, pandas-groupby, nan

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'ST': list('AABBBC'), 
         'NO': [5.3, 1.2, np.nan, 2.3, 4.2, 1.5],
         'CO':[3.4,np.nan, 4.1, 2.5,np.nan, 3.6]})
print (df)
  ST   NO   CO
0  A  5.3  3.4
1  A  1.2  NaN
2  B  NaN  4.1
3  B  2.3  2.5
4  B  4.2  NaN
5  C  1.5  3.6
```

[image]

How to groupby a column and count total numbers of other columns while excluding NaN in Python?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please add a [MCVE], it makes it easier for other users to reproduce your problem and increases the chance of getting an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.count`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.count.html) for count values excluding `NaN`s and reshape by [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) - output is `MultiIndex Series`:

```
s = df.groupby('ST').count().stack()
print (s)
ST    
A   NO    2
    CO    1
B   NO    2
    CO    2
C   NO    1
    CO    1
dtype: int64
```

If need `DataFrame`:

```
df1 = df.groupby('ST').count().stack().rename_axis(('ST','NEW')).reset_index(name='VAL')
print (df1)
  ST NEW  VAL
0  A  NO    2
1  A  CO    1
2  B  NO    2
3  B  CO    2
4  C  NO    1
5  C  CO    1
```

Comment: by the way, if I want to check how many negative numbers in one of the columns, how about the code? Thanks~

Comment: @JenniferChen - is possible be more specific? Maybe the best create new question, better is modify `df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'ST': list('AABBBC'), 
         'NO': [5.3, 1.2, np.nan, 2.3, 4.2, 1.5],
         'CO':[3.4,np.nan, 4.1, 2.5,np.nan, 3.6]})
print (df)` like pictures, because [this](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: never mind for this question, another question is, do you know how to write the series to csv or text file? cos my dataset is quite large, and the series length is long. Thanks~

Comment: Use `s.to_csv('file.txt')` or `s.to_csv('file.csv')` and for second `df1.to_csv('file.txt', index=False)`

Comment: @JenniferChen - then check [this](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) :)

Answer (score 0):

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
        {'ST': list('AABBBC'), 
         'NO': [5.3, 1.2, np.nan, 2.3, 4.2, 1.5],
         'CO':[3.4,np.nan, 4.1, 2.5,np.nan, 3.6]})
```

You can also do this in 2 steps with a combination of a melt and a pivot_table functions:
use a melt function to reformat shape of dataframe

```
cols=['NO','CO'] 

df_melt=pd.melt(df,id_vars=['ST'],value_vars=cols)
```

And then use a pivot table to create a new dataframe and count values

```
df_pivot=pd.pivot_table(df_melt,index=['ST','variable'],values='value',aggfunc='count').reset_index() 

Result:
    ST  variable    value
0   A   CO  1
1   A   NO  2
2   B   CO  2
3   B   NO  2
4   C   CO  1
5   C   NO  1
```